# Why is my Atom Text Editor font smaller and bold now?

Tags: atom-editor

After handing off my laptop to a peer while writing some code in the Atom Text Editor, my Atom text now appears to be bold and slightly smaller and a lower resolution.

I have tried uninstalling Atom and reinstalling as well as deleting the Atom directory to ensure that all of my settings were reset. I have also tried changing the syntax, zooming in and out, and changing the styles.less file to font-weight: lighter with no change. Changing it to font-weight: bold makes it even more bold, and font-weight: normal does nothing.

Here is what it should look like:

[image: how it should look]

This is from the Atom Dark Syntax Theme README. Note that all syntaxes are having this same problem, this is just an example.

Here is what it actually looks like:

[image: how it looks]

Can anyone explain what might have happened and how to change this back to the lighter, more defined text?

Comment: I assume you already looked into [this issue from github](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/6681) Is your font also blurry? That's what it looks like in the screenshot

Comment: @abhivemp, looked through that link you provided and it seems like they just needed to update atom, am I reading that right? I have everything up to date and uninstalled and reinstalled today. It also doesn't look like this was fully resolved before being closed out? I'm working at a bootcamp with other students using Atom and am the only one having this issue.

Comment: One thing that happened around the same time as this issue was the installation of Postman. I uninstalled it to see if it was related but have not seen any change.

Comment: you are right they closed the issue but didn't solve it. Postman wouldn't interfere with the atom settings. When you deleted the atom directory, did you also delete the .atom file? It's usually in your C: Drive

Comment: @abhivemp yes I did delete the .atom file as well

Comment: So when you are increasing font size, nothing is happening? When you mean by lower resolution, you have blurry font display? What packages do you have installed? the github link says the webkit was creating issues with the text

Comment: Increasing the font size makes the font bigger but it doesn't help with the boldness or the blurry font display, which is what I mean by lower resolution. I have advanced-open-file, atom-beautify, autoclose-html, autocomplpete-js-import, file-icons, and indent-guide-improved. I have not installed any new ones recently and when I deleted atom entirely and had zero packages it still had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This thread actually answers this fully and the last comment on the thread about editing the stylesheet with this helps for now, until the next update!

```
atom-text-editor .cursor {
  // border-color: red;
}
```

https://discuss.atom.io/t/editor-texts-are-slightly-more-bold/67107/10